# Not allowed to load local resource. Como se pueden mostrar archivos locales en una página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Muy buenas, me ha surgido un problema cuando trataba de mostrar unos PDF con un **window.open()**, la cuestión es que no tengo los PDF ubicados entre los archivos propios de la página, si no que son locales de una máquina diferente a la que yo trabajo.

Por lo tanto cuando trataba de simplemente abrir el archivo directamente, en la consola me aparecía el error: Not allowed to load local resource.

Ya he visto que esto se trata de una medida de seguridad que disponen los navegadores, y pese mirar formas de rodear el error, no he visto ninguna que me resulte práctica.

Mi escenario es el siguiente:
Dispongo de dos máquinas de trabajo, en una de ellas es donde se ubican todos los archivos relacionados con la página web, y en la otra es donde se ubica el programa y carpetas de gestión de la empresa en la que trabajo.

Me han solicitado realizar una página web que realice la función de CRM, y por lo tanto que realice las funciones que lleva a cabo el programa que utilizan para la gestión interna de la empresa.

EL problema me ha llegado cuando he necesitado recuperar unos PDF que se encuentran de forma local fuera del directorio de la página.

He probado a hacer la recuperación de los PDF mediante un encode a Base64 del archivo que buscaba y después situar el contenido de este en un iframe dentro de una nueva ventana del navegador, pero no he logrado que llegase a funcionar:

```
function verimagen() {
    var file = new File([""], "H:/OT/PROYECTOS/pdf1.pdf");
    var base64;
    getBase64(file).then(
        data => base64 = data   
    );
    
    console.log(base64);
    
    let pdfWindow = window.open("");
    pdfWindow.document.write(
        "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " +
        encodeURI(base64) + "'></iframe>"
    );
}

function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

He probado también creando un acceso directo de la carpeta donde se encuentran las imagenes y situando este en el directorio de la página, pero ya he podido ver que no sirve para nada.

Ya me he quedado sin ideas, y necesitaría alguna forma para poder acceder a estos archivos y abrirlos en una nueva pestaña de Google para poder visualizarlos.

No me sirve el copiar los archivos al directorio de la página web porque estamos hablando de un tamaño considerable de datos, y a parte de esto conllevaría el tener que realizar modificaciones en el propio programa de Gestión de la empresa.

Por lo tanto necesitaría que esto se realizase a nivel de la propia web. Decir que en esta dispongo de PHP y JQuery, para dar mas posibles soluciones.

Comment: No puedes. Por motivos de seguridad, el navegador bloqueará acceso a cualquier archivo local. Quizá podrías compartir la carpeta para darle acceso público y acceder a los archivos con `\\nombreDeEquipo\ruta\archivo.extension`

Comment: Me temo que esto lo he probado ya también, como ambas máquinas se encuentran en la misma red local, probé a compartir la carpeta en la red con acceso público, pero de igual manera continua saltando el mismo aviso y lo continua tratando como un archivo local. Gracias igualmente!

Comment: Entonces la opción sería que el segundo equipo tenga un servidor Web instalado (IIS, XAMPP, Wampserver, etc.) y acceder por IP y ruta.